# How Make a phone call in Windows 10 UAP

Tags: c#, windows

I found Windows.ApplicationModel.Calls API.I am searching alot of it but unable to find how to use it to make a call or launch different options available to make a call from my app.

Answer (score 2):

```
if (ApiInformation.IsApiContractPresent("Windows.ApplicationModel.Calls.CallsPhoneContract", 1,0))
{
    PhoneCallManager.ShowPhoneCallUI("0213132131", "my name");
}
```